# Creating a constructor, object type Circle

Tags: java, class

> write a constructor method with a parameters, an object of type Circle. The method should construct a new circle  object with the same field values as those of the parameter.

I found this really poorly worded and don't understand what exactly they are asking.  are they asking me to create a constructor like:

```
public Circle(int x, int y, int r)
{

}
```

do they want me to create a test class to create the object there and use the constructor to use the values ?

```
Circle c1 = new Circle (1,3,6);
```

Please help

Comment: Ask the people how gave you this homework.

Comment: I read it more as `public Circle(Circle useTheseMeasurements)`

Answer (score 2):

This is what i understand from your question

```
public Circle(Circle aCircle) {
   this.x = aCircle.getx();
   this.y = aCircle.gety();
   this.r = aCircle.getr();

 }
```

Comment: This is missing a return statement. It should create a new circle with these values and return it

Comment: @JohnSnow a constructor doesn't need a return statement.

Comment: @JohnSnow :  return in a contructor....!!!  this is not a method..  a contructor never return something

Comment: ah my bad. I was a bit too hasty when I read this part: `The method should construct a new circle object with the same field values as those of the parameter.`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think that what they are talking about

```
public Circle(int x, int y, int r){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.r=r;
    }

public Circle(Circle acircle){
    this(acicle.getx(),acicle.gety(),acicle.getz());
    }
```

not that "this" keyword can be used to call other constructors
see [this link about "this" keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: if you want to use .gety dont you have to make a constructor method?and would it look something like public double getx(){  return x; }

Comment: yes of course i've supposed that you have already wrote the getters "getx() and gety() and getr()"
or easily make x y r public and access them directly ex: aCycle.x ....